# Bug in AUnit which comes with GNAT

Tags: ada, gnat, aunit

I believe I have found and fixed a bug in AUnit which comes as part of the GNAT compiler tools for Ada.

What is the best way to submit bugs to AdaCore for their community versions of the GNAT tools?

The following program silently aborts with the current version of the compiler GNAT Community 2020 (20200429-84)

```
with Ada.Text_IO;use Ada.Text_IO;
with AUnit.Test_Filters;
with AUnit.Tests;

procedure Message_Allocation is

   package Filter_Package is
      type Filter_Type is new AUnit.Test_Filters.Name_Filter with null record;

      function Is_Active
     (Filter : Filter_Type;
      T      : AUnit.Tests.Test'Class) return Boolean;

   end Filter_Package;

   package body Filter_Package is
      function Is_Active
     (Filter : Filter_Type;
      T      : AUnit.Tests.Test'Class) return Boolean is begin return true; end is_active;
   end Filter_Package;

   filter : Filter_Package.filter_type;

begin
   Put_Line ("set 1st filter");
   filter.set_name ("abc");
   Put_Line ("set 2nd filter");
   filter.set_name ("xyz");
   Put_Line ("2nd filter set");

end Message_Allocation;
```

The bug is in the procedure Message_Free in the file aunit.adb. The following is the patched version. The change is the parameter to the call to AUnit.Memory.AUnit_Free.

```
   procedure Message_Free (Msg : in out Message_String) is
   begin
      if Msg /= null then
         AUnit.Memory.AUnit_Free (Msg.all'address - System.Address'size/8);
         Msg := null;
      end if;
   end Message_Free;
```

Comment: `System.Address'size/8` looks ... a bit off. Should it be `System.Address'size/System.Storage_Unit`?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, there are literal 8’s in Message_Alloc. I think it should actually be `Bounds’Object_Size / 8` (`Bounds` is two ints)

Answer (score 2):

A mail to: report (at) (the name of the company which makes GNAT) .com

You increase your chances with a meaningful title, and useful information to show the bug (typically a reproducer example) and your fix.

Answer (score 1):

Extending [@Zerte answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100899/2616032): There also available two other options:

1. You can report bug, propose pull request at public AUnit repository at Github:

   https://github.com/AdaCore/aunit

   In my opinion this can be better option than my second proposition
2. You could use contact web form for the community version of the AdaCore software here:

   https://www.adacore.com/community/contact

   From my own experience, you can get pretty fast answer there.

Comment: If you aren’t set up on Github, I could do this for you (by the way, congratulations on finding this if the error messages were as unhelpful as they were on macOS!)